# Embed slides from another PowerPoint presentation

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

Is there any way to really **reuse existing slides** by **embedding/linking** them to a new presentation?

I know the "Reuse slide" features and have read the 15679 tutorials copy-pasted from the official MS documentation.

I've tried it but when I update the source slide the destination slide is not updated.

The feature exists for **Excel spreadsheets** and **Visio drawings** that you can embed inside your new presentation.

When you change the spreadsheet or drawing your **presentation is updated** and this is really convenient.

Seems pretty obvious that this kind of feature exists for Powerpoint itself but with MS we never know. ;)

-

Does such a feature exist?

If no what are the other alternatives?

-

Thanks in advance.

---

**Update**: it was obvious finally, see my answer below.

This is indeed similar to what we do for Visio.

But I didn't remembered it and instinctively asked to Google.

Bad reflex because this time Google didn't do its job correctly and it only shows these copy/pasted tutorials without any added value compared to the MS docs and which are not at all relevant for my issue.

Not really Google's fault because all this stuff is from well referenced web-sites Google trusts, and the useful stuff is probably buried at the 4517th page. Nothing is perfect. :)

So I was fooled by all these tutorials which are all about another issue.

Conclusion: Google is not always your friend and using your brain can sometimes help too. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simple: copy from the source presentation.

And special-copy as a link to Microsoft PowerPoint Slide Object.

I just had to resize the target object to fill the entire destination slide.