# Is there a way to referentially import one pptx into another?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I often create presentations that consist of parts that are shared between two or more of them. Let's say they look something like this:

```
Pres 1:
 - intro
 - section a
 - section b
 - outro

Pres 2:
 - intro
 - section a
 - some extra slides
 - section c
 - outro
```

etc.

I know I can import the slides for section a from Pres1 when creating Pres2. However, this has a few problems if I ever update anything about the slides (even as minor as correcting a typo).

- If I want create a Pres3 that also uses section a, I need to remember which of the old presentations has the most up-to-date version of that section.
- If I want to re-use Pres1 at a later date, I need to remember whether I did any updates to section a in one of the other presentations and need to copy those changes over.

For me, I would be far easier to use a book-and-chapter approach similar to Latex's /include command. I would have have one autoritative version of each section and then refer to that version from other presentations, such that the most recent version of section a is loaded when opening Pres 1. (It could also remain the same for the moment and require a manual re-sync, the important part is the link to the source document)

Is something like that possible in Powerpoint? Either natively or with add-ons?

---

(I saw [Embed slides from another PowerPoint presentation](https://superuser.com/questions/733938/embed-slides-from-another-powerpoint-presentation), however, that seems to relate to importing individual slides, not entire presentations or even sections)

Comment: How will you use these presentations?  If you're using them for slide shows, there's a fairly simple way of doing what you want.  But if you need to print them, it gets more complicated; may not be possible.

Comment: For Slideshows, so that seems to be good news.

Answer (score 0):

Now that we've established that this will be used as a slideshow, try this:

In Presentation 1, add all the slides that are unique to that presentation.
Put all of the "shared" content (ie, Section A, B etc) into individual separate files.

Wherever you want to insert the shared content into a presentation, LINK to the individual presentation that contains the content.

When you give the presentation and reach that point, PPT will open the linked file but the main presentation will remain open, "behind the scenes".  When the linked section ends, the presentation will close and  you'll be back at the main presentation on the slide you linked from.

The only other thing to remember is to set PPT NOT to end presentations with a black slide.  That setting is in File | Options.

Comment: Late followup, but that does sound great. However, I couldn't find how to link to another PPT in the way you specified. Do you maybe have a resource on how to do that, or a quick hint on where to find it in the menus?

Comment: Select the text or shape you want to click to launch another presentation, then press CTRL+K to open the link dialog. On the left of the dialog, choose "Existing file", then browse to select the file you want to link to.  Word to the wise:  Save your main presentation to a working folder, then put all the files you want to link to in the same folder BEFORE you start linking.  This will save trouble down the road.